# Combining two profiles to a volume using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm interested in trying to create a surf fin. Is it possible to combine two profile curves to create a volume in Blender such as can be done in Rhino + Grasshopper? I am able to create the profile using curves, but am not sure how the two can be "blended".

[image]
The reference paper: http://www.cad-journal.net/files/vol_18/CAD_18(2)_2021_297-308.pdf

Comment: Seeing as this is based on a specific article about some specific *other* software, I think you may need the expertise of someone proficient in both Rhino's Grasshopper *and* Blender's Geometry Nodes to sort of "port" the technique over. Is the ultimate goal to 3D print a variety of different fins by tweaking the parameters of the node setup? Or do you just need one fin? If just one fin, I might suggest keeping it simple and going the polygon mesh with subsurf route. Bear in mind Blender is primarily a 3D animation suite, and you're comparing it to CAD software for product design here.